# XML SVG : Make coordinates of a Rect dynamic

Tags: xml, svg

I'm creating custom dynamic SVG where I want to make the X and Y property of a rect element dynamic like below:

```html
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  viewBox="0 0 110 40">
  <defs>
    <ref id="abs" param="abs" default="5"/>
    <ref id="ord" param="ord" default="5"/>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <rect x="url(#abs)" y="url(#ord)" width="25" height="25" fill="purple"/>
  </g>
  <script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/modules/ref/master/ref2.js"/>
</svg>
```

I'm calling my SVG into the webpage with that code :

```html
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="bidule.svg?abs=0&ord=0" id="svg"></object>
```

But i'm facing an issue with X and Y props, when I load it on chrome, the following error is triggered : `<rect> attribute x: Expected length, "url(#abs)"`

Nota : I know how to do that in JS SVG, but I must do it in "native" SVG because it will be embedded.

What's the right method to do that?

Comment: The error you get is just that the values of attributes x and y can only be either  <length>|<percentage> [`<rect>` - SVG: Scalable Vector Graphics | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect#attributes). The script that you include in the SVG is replacing what value after the error occur (at least that is the intend).

Comment: Are you running this from a webserver? I just tested your code and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps you.  But you can do something similar with CSS variables.

This won't work with `<object>` though, so you would probably need to inline the SVG on the page.

```css
svg rect {
  --abs: 25px;
  --ord: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  viewBox="0 0 110 40">
  <style>
    :root {
      --abs: 5px;
      --ord: 5px;
    }
    rect {
      x: var(--abs);
      y: var(--ord);
  </style>
  <g>
    <rect width="25" height="25" fill="purple"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```